# How do I get the timezone initials?

Tags: c, datetime, timezone

I am trying to create a `Date` header for an email.

The format is as follows:

```
DayOfWeek, Day ShortMonth Year Hours:Minutes:Seconds Offset (TimeZone)
```

So an example would be:

```
Fri, 19 Mar 2010 11:44:09 -0700 (PDT)
```

Its the TimeZone part (`PDT` in the example) that I'm trying to get. I realize that this will be different across systems, but I'd like a solution for all of them.

Thanks!

Comment: Hm, are you sure about that format? I've just looked through [RFC 822](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/#z28) and it seems to allow only either numeric or string format, not both at the same time.

Comment: @MichałGórny lol, I was just copying what GMail does. Didnt read the rfc.

Comment: And [RFC 2822](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.3) says that the names are obsolete, and the new format is just `+NNNN` or `-NNNN`.

Comment: Thanks, I was just trying to be compatible with GMail and hopefully by extension everyone else. I'll add it if I can figure out how to do so, but i guess, as you point out, it isnt critical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `%Z` in `strftime()`.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[16];
    time_t t = time(0);

    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Z", localtime(&t));
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

And it's C89, AFAIR (which means it's very portable).

Snippet from the C99 standard:

> `%Z` is replaced by the locale’s time zone name or abbreviation, or by no characters if no time zone is determinable. [`tm_isdst`]

Sadly, as we noticed not every system gives reasonable values for it...

Comment: Hmm, give me a minute. I'll start my Windows and see what it gives.

Comment: Try [setlocale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) before the [strftime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) call,

Comment: I have a bad news. It works on my MinGW but appends `(summer time)` to the result, so that implementation won't really help.

Comment: @chacham15: Well, I have another suggestion. Is it acceptable for you to just give time in UTC (`gmtime()`), and append `UTC` by hand? I think that's only really portable way of getting standards-compliant timezone without depending on additional libraries.

Comment: @MichałGórny how can it not work on mine but work on yours? that wont work because it will confuse someone when they look at the sent at timestamp.

Comment: @chacham15: well, that can be a few things I can think of. Starting with Windows version (mine is XP), maybe some configuration options, MinGW version, the fact that I was using msys to run the program...

Comment: [Apparently it's a question of Regional Settings](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vclanguage/thread/a87e1d25-fb71-4fe0-ae9c-a9578c9753eb) ... you might like to try [GetTimeZoneInformation()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the system dlls.

Comment: @MichałGórny wow, thats is interesting. I was running it in cygwin. I ran it again in msys and it worked (well, i got the full name like you did).

Comment: @pmg yea, i think they are right, im also getting the same string. i.e. not the abbreviated time zone, but the full name

Comment: @chacham15 - Your comments really help me figured out why my selenium test are failing due to wrong time. My case is I ran our build/test script from a Cygwin Shell and it launch Firefox in the wrong time zone (running the following from the console `new Date()` prints out timezone (ric)). Thanks!

Run `unset TZ` in the cygwin shell resolved the issue. This [page](http://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin/2012-03/msg00048.html) provides more background information.